# Retrieving a random word from a textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

Making a hangman game, trying to retrieve a word from a text file

```
import time
import random

def start():
    f = open(“wordlist.txt”).read()
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            hangman = random.choice(word)
```

I expected it to retrieve a random word from the text file, but when i implement a print option to check, it print the ENTIRE list, leading me to belive it’s not picking one word.

The print functions I tried were:

```
print(hangman)
```

And

```
print(word)
```

This is the list in the text file:

```
Python
Program
rrrrr
mario
luigi
bowser
peach
daisy
wario
waluigi
yoshi
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Could you also provide a sample of the text doc?

Comment: `open(“wordlist.txt”).read()` reads the entire file. Use `open(“wordlist.txt”)` if you want to read the file line-by-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over each word, you can read all lines with `readlines` and use `choice` to pick a random line. So you can avoid some common mistakes. In you example you iterate over each word and you update the variable`hangman` in every step. I think this is not want you want to do?

```
import random

with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
    print(random.choice(f.readlines()))
```